# Resctrict date in datepicker

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker

I have some datepicker which use in check in and check out date. I want to restrict check in date just until 31 December every year and cannot display 1 january in next year. And in the check out date it just display 1 january in next year. Example, I can check in on 31 December 2016 but I just can check out in 1 january 2017, cannot in 2 January 2017.

I have tried code like this but not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Check In : <input type="text" id="datepicker-13"></p><br>
<p>Check Out : <input type="text" id="datepicker-14">

</body>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var today = new Date();
        var lastDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), 11, 31);
        $('#datepicker-13').datepicker({
            maxDate: lastDate
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var today = new Date();
        var lastDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), 11, 32);
        $('#datepicker-14').datepicker({
            maxDate: lastDate
        });
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Did you read the documentation, specfically the part about `minDate` and `maxDate` settings

Comment: Yes, I read that but I dont understand it. @adeneo

Comment: Are you using jQuery datepicker?

Comment: Yes I using jQuery datepicker @Ronald

Comment: @Nicholas, does my answer work for you?

Comment: Hi @Ronald I've been try your code but it's not working enough. I just edited my post with my code.

Comment: @Ronald I changed using bootstrap datepicker now

Comment: @Nicholas What do you mean it's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use maxDate of the datepicker UI.

For check-in:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var today = new Date();
    var lastDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), 11, 31);
    $('#check-in').datepicker({
        maxDate: lastDate
    });
});
```

This will limit up to December 31 of current year.

For check-out:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var today = new Date();
    var lastDate = new Date(today.getFullYear(), 11, 32);
    $('#check-out').datepicker({
        maxDate: lastDate
    });
});
```

This will limit up to January 1 of next year.